# CLion quick run with arguments

Tags: command-line-arguments, clion

I know that I can specify program arguments in CLion with Edit configurations, but I find it quite inconvenient when I want to quickly run the program with new arguments and don't want to store it in a separate run configuration. Is there something like a shortcut displaying dialog with arguments input?

I know I can always use terminal, but I'd like to have an access to CLion's GUI debugger.

Comment: No there isn't (as far as I know), but if you go to [the CLion issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) and add it as a suggestion they might consider adding it.